# How to open a file in Python Shell for Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome

Generally, opening a file in Python is simplicity itself with `open`. But this environment is special - it's [Python Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-shell/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia?hl=en) installed on a Chromebook.

My questions are two-fold:

1. How do I know what path to use, to access a USB stick for example?
2. Will Chrome even allow the file access, or will it be blocked by a sandbox?

Ideally I'd like to open the file through the file dialog that pops up to upload a file to a web server, which would solve both problems. Anybody know how?